# Getting Laravel htaccess to listen to my rewrites

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I'm trying to rewrite some old site pages to routes on my shiny new Laravel site. I understand in principle how .htaccess works, but there's a line in the default Laravel .htaccess which (I think) is throwing my own rewrites. So, this is something like what I am trying to do:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(\d+)*$ ./users
```

However, Laravel already has this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Which effectively says "If the user request is for any file or folder that does not exist, pipe their request through to index.php" - the [L] meaning that this is the last rule for these conditions.

My problem with this is, where do I put my rewrite instructions? If I put it after that rule then surely my rewrite will be ignored as everything is already being sent to index.php (if htaccess rules are sequential)

If I put my rule before Laravel's default rules, does that mean that my rule will mess up what Laravel is trying to do? At the moment, wherever I put my rule, I just get various result ranging from a 500 error to a blank page with no content.

How can I integrate my own rules into Laravel's .htaccess file without stepping on Laravel?

Comment: You need to do it before the Laravel default rules. And this should probably use [L] as well, so that it stops the other rules from processing in the same round. I am not sure however if REQUEST_FILENAME changes accordingly, if you rewrite the path internally. If it doesn’t, then you might need to either rewrite externally, or modify the Laravel default rules as well. Before that, check what the error log has to says about those 500.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. Will try that straight away...

Comment: Right. You were spot on and this works. Many thanks. Can't mark your comment as a correct answer though... Can you make your comment the answer and I'll mark it as correct. Otherwise I can write up an answer using your information and mark that as correct if that suits you better?

Comment: Happy to let you write up your own answer, my input on this was rather minimal :)

Comment: ok. Well just for others who like me find writing .htaccess stuff like stepping through a minefield :-)

Comment: @Wittner How did you do it? Not sure if I need the same solution.

Comment: @davejal for me it was the order of the rules, so just make sure to place your specific commands before Laravel's.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that Laravel's .htaccess file rules do not conflict with yours, you need to ensure that your rules come before theirs. I am supplying a sample of my .htaccess files with path names changed, each line annotated so that it makes sense to those who are facing the sam problem:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    # Make sure Rewrite engine is running
      RewriteEngine On

    # Make sure base of site is set to root (othwerwise you can get results like /var/www/public_html/ before the results pages)
      RewriteBase /

    # For all directory requests in the url (d) e.g. blah.com/directory/
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # And for all file requests in the url (f) e.g. blah.com/directory/page.php
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Check for the CONDition that the page has 'product_id' in the url e.g. http:/www.blah.com/show_product.php?product_id=273
      RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product_id=(.*)$
    # If the condition above was met, then check if the page is called list_products.php, if it is, redirect the browser to /product/ with the product id (273) as %1
      RewriteRule ^list_products.php$ product\/%1? [R=301,L]

    # Simpler redirect for pages without a url variable
      Redirect /car-hire.php https://www.blah.com/car-hire

    # Then comes Laravel’s .htaccess stuff
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

It seems (as CBroe kindly answered in his comment) that keeping your rules ‘on top’ of Laravel’s as above is the answer